# Korn Shell Script setting arguments to variables, adding up and averaging, and if-else problems

Tags: shell, variables, unix, arguments

I am writing a program using a Korn shell script that is actually using 2 different scripts, one called grade.sh, the other called GRADE.sh. In GRADE.sh it's supposed to take in 6 arguments and set them equal to variables, then print those variables and find the sum of your grades as well as the average of your grade. It is then supposed to determine your letter grade based on your average. grade.sh is basically a formatting script to print out the contents of GRADE.sh in an organized manner. Here's the code. I'm having trouble getting the sum and average, and also having trouble with the if statements. If you could help me find out where I'm doing something wrong I'd greatly appreciate it!

grade.sh:

```
#! /bin/ksh
#Description: Prints out a grade report for multiple students.

printf "Date:"
printf "`date|cut -c1-10`,"
printf `date|cut -c25-28`
printf "\n"
print "Name  Prog  Labs  Midterm  Final  Total  Avg  Grade"

GRADE.sh Akers John 90 88 80 70
GRADE.sh Eckert Hester 80 90 67 89
GRADE.sh Spence Frances 70 81 78 85
GRADE.sh Shaw Mary 88 79 90 78
GRADE.sh Gates William 67 66 80 90
GRADE.sh Thompson Ken 80 60 90 89
```

GRADE.sh:

```
#! /bin/ksh
#Description: Calculate total score and average of a student's grades.

fName=$2
lName=$1
prog=$3
lab=$4
mid=$5
final=$6

sum= $prog+$lab+$mid+$final
avg= $sum/4

printf "$fName $lName $prog $lab $mid $final"

if($avg>=90&&$avg<=100)
then
    printf "%s" A
    printf "\n"
elif($avg>=80&&$avg<90)
then
    printf "%s" B
    printf "\n"
elif($avg>=70&&$avg<80)
then
    printf "%s" C
    printf "\n"
elif($avg>=60&&$avg<70)
then
    printf "%s" D
    printf "\n"
else
    printf "%s" F
    printf "\n"
fi
```

I apologize in advance, pretty new to coding in Korn Shell, and this is my first post on here. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please post error messages if there are any, or sample output that is not what you expected.

Comment: never have a space after your `=` signs AND you need to use the shell arthimetic evaluation, so `sum=$(($prog+$lab+$mid+$final))` And finally, when referencing variables inside the arthimetic eval, you don't need the `$`s on each variable, so `sum=$(( prog + lab + mid + final ))`. Good luck.

Comment: arg... and don't use `( )` pairs when testing math conditions, use `elif (( avg >= 60 && avg < 70 )) ; then` ... AND you can condense your date parsing to `printf "Date: $(date|cut -c1-10,25-28)\n"`, although the output from my date cmd looks a little dodgy, you may want to experiment with different ranges on your `-c` options. Finally, most recent OS's support direct date formating, like `printf $(date +"Date: %Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S\n"). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something to get you started. Note that you don't need two scripts. You can create a function that does the grading and call that function within your script. You can use `if .. then .. else`, I just showed you another option using a `case` statement. Also, if you are using `printf` then use it's ability to format the output. I will leave that up to you.

```
#!/bin/ksh

get_grade() {
    local fName=$2
    local lName=$1
    local prog=$3
    local lab=$4
    local mid=$5
    local final=$6
    local sum=$((prog + lab + mid + final))
    local avg=$((sum / 4))

    printf "$fName $lName $prog $lab $mid $final"

    case 1 in 
        $((avg >= 90 && avg <= 100)))
            printf " %s\n" A ;;
        $(( avg >= 80 && avg < 90)))
            printf " %s\n" B ;;
        $((avg >= 70 && avg < 80)))
            printf " %s\n" C ;;
        $((avg >= 60 && avg < 70)))
            printf " %s\n" D ;;
        *)
            printf " %s\n" F ;;
    esac
}
printf "$(date +"Date: %a %b %d, %Y")\n"
printf "Name  Prog  Labs  Midterm  Final  Total  Avg  Grade\n"

get_grade Akers John 90 88 80 70
get_grade Eckert Hester 80 90 67 89
get_grade Spence Frances 70 81 78 85
get_grade Shaw Mary 88 79 90 78
get_grade Gates William 67 66 80 90
get_grade Thompson Ken 80 60 90 89
```

#### Output:

```
Date: Sat Apr 05, 2014
Name  Prog  Labs  Midterm  Final  Total  Avg  Grade
John Akers 90 88 80 70 B
Hester Eckert 80 90 67 89 B
Frances Spence 70 81 78 85 C
Mary Shaw 88 79 90 78 B
William Gates 67 66 80 90 C
Ken Thompson 80 60 90 89 C
```

Comment: The `printf "Date: $(date +...)"; printf "\n"` should arguably be refactored to simply `date +"Date: %a %b %d, %Y"`

Comment: Also, better to make the script read stdin and avoid mixing code and data.

Comment: @tripleee Agree, but I wasn't sure how OP wanted to feed data to the script. His question showed two scripts (with similar names).